# How do I get the current line count from xargs?

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I want to grab every 5 images in a directory and merge them together into a new file with a unique filename per 5 image group.

```
find *.jpg | xargs -n 5 -i convert {} -append {#}.png
```

This is really close but the {#} doesn't output the current line count.  Is this even possible with xargs?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but the `{#}` looks suspiciously like the job number from gnu parallel, so you might want to consider using that as a replacement.

Comment: Yes! I have a working copy in parallel.  Just hoping that xarg could do the trick too...

Comment: @Jason A lot of people considering `xargs` are unaware of `parallel --embed`. Are you one of them?

Answer (score 4):

If the filenames does not contain whitespaces:

Dry run:

```
find *.jpg | xargs -n 5 | awk '{OFS=" ";}{print "convert",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,"-append",NR".png\n";}'
```

If everything looks okay, append `| sh`.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
set -- ./**/*.jpg(N.)
n=0
while (($# >= 5)) {
  convert $@[1,5] -append $((++n)).png
  shift 5
}
```

That one should work whatever characters are in the file names, and the list of files is sorted. Hidden files and directories are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you can do it with `parallel`. If you still want to use xargs, you can
add an `echo` to the xargs command to just
get the command printed, then post-process the output with awk to
replace the last word with a suitable counted filename (with leading 0's for easy listing):

```
find . -name '*.jpg' | xargs -n 5 -i echo convert {} -append {#}.png |
awk '{ $NF = sprintf("%04d.png", i); i++; print }' |
bash
```

(You are lucky, my xargs doesnt let me mix -i and -n). This wont work if you have spaces in the filenames. I used `find . -name` in case you have too many files and the `*.jpg` is too large to expand. (add `-maxdepth 1` if you dont want to go into subdirs).

So perhaps it's simpler to do it all in awk:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' |
awk '{ files = files " " $1 }
 NR%5 == 0 { printf("convert %s -append %04d.png\n",files,i); i++; files="" }
 END { if(files!="")printf("convert %s -append %04d.png\n",files,i) } ' |
bash
```

The `END` part handles cases where there are not a multiple of 5 files at the end.

Comment: Can you share how to do that with parallel in your answer?

Comment: @charlie_pl It wasn't me who did it with parallel, but the original poster, Jason. You should add your comment to his question so he will see it.